# Recording sound, and then using/saving it on Android

Tags: java, android, audio, media-player, recording

I want to add a feature into my app where you can record sound and then use it within the app (MediaPlayer)

How can I do this?

- How do I record sound?
- How do I get it into a Mediaplayer?
- Does it have to be saved? or can it go from being recorded -> into app straight away...

Comment: A link-only answer below [gives this link](http://www.benmccann.com/dev-blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/). It may be deleted by the Review Queue, so I will preserve it here.

Answer (score 0):

Use AudioRecord class.